# facing constraints red line on storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

[image: the first picture showing the red lines]

[image: the second picture showing the constraints]

I have a view which is resizable.
When I set the relation as equal, I don't see any red lines but I see console error about constraints. but when I set it like the second picture, I don't see any error but I see the red lines on storyboard.
What I have tried is to set the priority of top and left as 750 but It doesn't seem it works for me.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: try to give the left constraint a normal priority of 1000

Comment: @MohmmadS I gave 1000 to it but still the red line...

Comment: what Xcode tells you about it

Comment: @MohmmadS top is 750, other than this, the others are 1,000 and I don't see any error but I still see the red lines on storyboard.

Comment: Tell us in your own words how you want the view to appear. Things like “I want the view to be centered”, “I want it to grow on larger devices, but maintain its relative shape”. “I want it to be as big as possible while always 10 points from the edges”.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting XCode, if you think there is no constraint error and it is only showing in the storyboard.

Even after restarting if you see the red lines then post the error warning that you can see in the View Controller Scene next to storyboard.